# Is there any possible way to change a memory location to a shared memory in C?

Tags: c, posix, shared-memory, sysv

In c you can do

```
shmid = shmget(SHMEM_KEY, sizeof(int*) * n , SHEMEM_MODE | IPC_CREAT);
int* shmem = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
```

to assign first given free memory space as a shared memory.

Is there any way to assigne current memory space as a shared memory?

Comment: I wouldn't think so. I think (but don't quote me) that the difference between private and shared memory is where it is located. So I don't think that you can "assign" A memory location as shared. But, I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You use [`shmat()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/shmat) to alias the shared memory you created to any arbitrary page-aligned range in your address-space

So this isn't taking some memory you already have and publishing it; its taking some new shared memory, you then copy what you want to publish across, then use `shmat` to alias it to where you had what you wanted to publish - this has the same effect.

Comment: I'm not very clear, could you possibly disambiguate by actual syntax?

Answer (score 0):

First I would advise not to use the oldish `shmget` interfaces but the
more modern POSIX interfaces `shm_open` and `mmap` (if you have them,
you didn't specify your system)

Then the `mmap` allows you to propose an address in your address space
where you'd like to have the segment

this is not exactly what you are asking for, but the closest you can
get, I think